# плагин woocommerce-subscriptions

Tags: woocommerce

[image: плагин woocommerce-subscriptions]

Вопрос такой: у меня есть приложение оно браузерное (https://dcaplan.ru/Avtomat/index.html) создана через конструктор 3
хочу на сайте сделать подписку скачал плагин `woocommerce-subscriptions` настроил покупку, где найти куда сохраняются данные, там где подписка активна, чтоб я смог занести в приложение если подписка активна то доступ получен.

вот скрин на ней написано активна, но ищу в базе данных там нету сохранений, получается он сохраняет в какой-то файл или куда откуда можно вытащить действие и сравнить (https://disk.yandex.ru/d/9XTzpsemz7S9gQ) ссылка на плагин

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.